# Using a section footer view to add a row to the section where the footer view is?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I would like to know if it is possible to create a `UITableView` that, when the user taps a section footer view (containing a `UIButton`, let's say), adds a row to the section where the tapped section footer view is.

While attempting to create such a `UITableView`, I realised that there is a major challenge, that I cannot obtain a reference to the section in which the tapped section footer view is. As such I cannot use methods like `insertRows(at:with:)` to do the required addition.

Is there any way to obtain the reference to the row? Or any methods to work around such that the `UITableView` "knows" where to insert the row when the section footer view is tapped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you could do this, but the easiest is probably to add a gesture recogniser to your footer view - you don't need a button, you can check for a click anywhere, but your design may be better with a button depending on what you include in the footer view.

You can use the `tag` attribute to keep a track of the section, and the processing is easy.

Here's a quick example, where I have just assumed `data1` and `data2` are presented in the two sections

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableViewCell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    if indexPath.section == 0
    {
        cell.textLabel?.text = data1[indexPath.row]
    }
    else
    {
        cell.textLabel?.text = data2[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: 30))
    footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    footerView.tag = section

    let clickGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector(self.didClickFooter))
    footerView.addGestureRecognizer(clickGesture)


    return footerView
}
@objc func didClickFooter(sender : UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // Do what you want here, once you identify the section

    if sender.view!.tag == 0
    {
        data1.append("new data1")
    }
    else
    {
        data2.append("new data2")
    }
    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Purely out of curiosity, what are the other approaches that can work as well, other than adding gesture recognizer?

Comment: I think you should be able to work your way back up the hierarchy of views, and find the section that way - but that seems overly complex.  Depending on your data model, you can sometimes just set a flag when you select - but that's a bit clunky.  You could add a specific button to each footer, and run the update there - but the generic approach seems more elegant